# Read CSV file with x/y to shapefile in standalone PyQGIS Script

Tags: pyqgis, standalone, pycharm

I have read quite a few Q&As on this topic so far but still I have problems with correct import CSV file.
I'm working in PyCharm and trying write function which will read CSV and save as vector file. In QGIS the console works fine but PyCharm is blowing up when I execute one line:

```
def read_csv(csv_path, encoding, delimiter, long, lat, crs):
    file_path = 'file:///' + csv_path
    uri = filepath + f'?encoding={encoding}&delimiter={delimiter}&xField={long}&yField={lat}&crs={crs}
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Name', 'delimitedtext') --> here PyCharm cruches
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output, encoding, crs, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Seems there is something wrong with layer. When I'm importing f.i. polygon *.shp everything works fine.

IDE - PyCharm 2021

QGIS version - 3.10 (...i know, old)

Error code in PyCharm: -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? What is the value of uri?

Comment: Actually Pycharm returns an error mentioned in post. Uri value :    uri = 'f:///E:/..... csv?encoding=UTF-8&delimiter=,&xField=x&yField=y&crs=epsg:4326'